# How do I parse a byte array removing all non-ASCII bytes?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arrays, ascii

I'm trying to log a bluetooth connection in an Android app (non-malicious, it's logging diagnostics).  However, the transmissions and responses are in byte arrays and contain non-ASCII bytes.  Trying to log the raw byte array gives about 20 spaces between every other character.

How can I remove all non-ASCII bytes?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the byte array and append each byte that *is* in the ASCII range to a `StringBuilder`. Remember to cast them to `char` such that you get `append(char)` rather than `append(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are bothering to log the data at all perhaps you should log the hex-encoding of the data. That way you'll preserve all the information present. If you really want to see only the ASCII characters you can post-process the log information to give you an ASCII view of it when you want.

Comment: What it is.  That's the deeper question.  However, since this is on a phone, I can't exactly do much post-processing.  I'm most likely not going to have access to the machines where the data is viewed.